lightdm re-login while shutting down
I have a weird effect that shows only occasionally.
System

Ubuntu MATE 22.04.
X11 with lightdm as display manager
lightdm is configured to auto-login and also re-login within 2s after a session ends

Setup

System boots
lightdm starts a graphical session (in fact it is configured to start a single application in kiosk mode)
After users have finished working they press a reboot button within this application
If this button is pressed the system performs a shutdown -r now

This results in

The application being closed
The session falling back to the login
lightdm being shutdown
The rest of the system shutting down

In rare occasions, however, this happens

The application closes
The session falling back to the login
The shutdown of the rest of the system is held up by something (currently not known what this is. Suspecting some mounted devices)
In meantime lightdm performs a re-login
The application starts up again
Then finally the shutdown commences
The upstarting graphics session is being killed together with the application, which causes some problems, we would like to prevent.

My Questions

Is there a way to prevent lightdm from doing an autologin while a shutdown is in progress?
Should we assess this a bug in lightdm?
(Although I didn't find a suitable issue for lightdm)
How could I find what is slowing down shutdown? (I know, solving this, would only hide the race condition taking place between the re-login and the hanging shutdown. However, it should be addressed, too)

